# Invalid use of incomplete class - Better to just have a single header than one including the other?

Tags: c++, class

I have created two classes, Card and Monster, with Card containing a function that is friendly to Monster. Monster produces a compile error saying "invalid use of incomplete type class Card" on the line of the friend statement.

From my research I've found that one way to fix this is #include Card.h into Monster.h (as it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)).
Is there really a reason, if you're only going to use one of the header files as in that example, to make two? Is it just not acceptable to have more than one class to a header file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Comment: how about showing us some code?

Comment: `friend class Card;` should be enough. You don't need all of `Card` to just make it a friend.

Answer (score 1):

Different classes are different entities, so you want to keep them apart.
You wont put their header files together from the same reason you put them in different files in the first place.